# Caching dataset in SparkML Transformer

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-ml

I am trying to use *Spark ML Transformers* in a Pipeline. One task in this pipeline is to join the incoming *Dataset* to *existing reference* data using a **`join`** key.

The reference data is large, but can be pre-partitioned on the `join` key. If I want to use this transformer many times, but only want to load the reference data into memory once, **when in the lifecycle of the transformer can I cache the reference data?** (Can assume the reference data is in a parquet file somewhere)

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you actually need to cache at the Spark layer.  Reading Parquet is fast, networked filesystems are fast, and OS buffer caches are surprisingly large.  Depending on your environment and working set size, you may not need to cache at the Spark layer (and doing so may even hurt performance).

If you determine that it makes sense to cache in general, the problem is a little trickier because you want to do the right thing even if someone passes you something that's already cached (in that case, you don't need to cache it and wouldn't want to uncache it at some point in the future). You can check to see if the dataset is cached before caching it:

`if (refdata.storageLevel == StorageLevel.NONE) refdata.cache()`

Conditionally caching the reference data in this way is appropriate to do when you're actually constructing the `Transformer`, since the `cache` will have no effect until the reference data are accessed.

When to uncache the data is a trickier problem.  If someone (even you) has passed you cached reference data, then you didn't cache it (and you'll not want to uncache it later, so as not to surprise them).  If you track whether or not you cached the reference data in your `Transformer` (e.g., in a value named `uncached`), then you should have a method that cleans up if necessary, and call that explicitly when you're done.

Putting it all together, your Transformer would look something like this:

```
class ExampleModel(private val uncached: Boolean, private val refdata: Broadcast[DataFrame]) extends Model[Example] {

  def this(df: Broadcast[DataFrame]) {
    this(df.value.storageLevel == StorageLevel.NONE, df)
  }

  if(uncached) refdata.value.cache();

  // ...

  def cleanup { if (uncached) { refdata.value.uncache() } ; refdata.destroy() }

}
```

Comment: Transformers need to be serializable (usually with default constructor and Params with getter and setter if using DefaultParamsWritable). I don't think I can pass refdata to the constructor because it won't serialize like a regular parameter.

Comment: @DanielMelemed good point, and something I overlooked in producing an illustrative code example.  However, you can certainly broadcast data frames; I've updated the example to reflect this.